# Compiling a php extension into a dll

Tags: php, windows, dll, php-extension, php-internals

I've been attempting for a last few days to make use of the operator overloading extension (pecl.php.net/package/operator), which has apparently been updated recently to be compatible with 5.3 and 5.4.

I've tried compiling it in windows (64-bit Windows 7) using [this guide](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild), with PHP 5.4 and Windows SDK 7.1 without luck. So I tried doing it with PHP 5.3 and Windows SDK 6.1 and I can get it to successfully compile with the config "configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-operator" and then "nmake". The problem is that it doesn't produce a dll file for the operator extension, instead what I get [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcdWi.png), which is apparently useless for me. What I want is a dll I can use for my local WampServer setup.

I had had fatal errors when trying to use operator-0.4.1 from the pecl.php.net site, so instead I downloaded and compiled from the git repository (github.com/php/pecl-php-operator), which is what produced the .obj, .idb and .sbr files.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-operator=shared
```

otherwise it's statically compiled.

Anyway, if you want to use it with WampServer, the binary will probably not work because if I'm not mistaken WampServer is compiled against the VC10 C runtime library, while the guide you linked to instructs you to use Visual Studio 2008 (which comes with VC9). You'll need to use the VC10 compiler (I think it's bundled with Windows SDK 7.1, so you can download just that and skip Visual Studio).

Comment: I tried the above for my own extension, but it still produces a lib. I am using PHP 7.3 and VC15. How can I produce a DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Into extension root path, and modify `config.w32`

`EXTENSION('redis', sources);`  `to EXTENSION('redis', sources,true);`

```
buildconf --force

configure --enable-xx 

nmake
```

you'll get `php-redis.dll`

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles as me on an error while running `configure` with `--enable-XXX=shared`

```
WARNING                                                                                                                                                                                                     
The following arguments is invalid, and therefore ignored:                                                                                                            
 --enable-xdebug                                                                              
 --enable-ssh2
```

Then `configure --help` indeed is your friend. These modules are included like so

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-zlib --with-openssl --with-ssh2=shared --with-xdebug=shared
```